# DataGrip wrong character export to a file

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I'd like to ask how I solve the problem with DataGrip doing the wrong conversion of special characters. Chinese and Japanese characters are broken.

I see the correct characters in the DataGrip console after the query. But when I try to export this data into a CSV file, all these characters get broken there.

Comment: What DataGrip version, SQL dialect, and version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
I saved the file in csv and after I opened it with Excel. So Excel shows to me the wrong character.
The solution is to use another text editor.

Comment: An idea: your exported CSV file may not have a UTF8 BOM header (special first 3 bytes  in a file that tell that the file uses UTF-8 encoding) or whatever the encoding is used. try using "Import data from text file" functionality where Excel asks for column delimiters, what encoding is used etc. See if detects the right encoding there.